# Illegal Invocation within object using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, oop

So I got a dreaded Illegal Invocation error in Chrome. I'm using Web Audio API (HTML5 is awesome btw), to build a framework of audio effects and signal routing. Basically it automatically routes the nodes based on where in the array they are. But I included my own class/objects for complex effects, or modules. These have multiple nodes within them and can delogate what goes where as if it was a single input/output node.

Anyways, when the object is created it throws the error right at the point of node creation (the private one within the module). I've read about this happening with console a lot, or loss of inherent "this". But I don't know why its happening here since the variable to grab the node constructor is a global variable. Any ideas?

```
var context, nodes;

var Delay = function(_context, _time, _feedback, _wet) {
   this.type = "Delay";

   this.delay = new context.createDelayNode(); //Console points error here.
   this.feedback = new context.createGainNode();
   this.crossfade = new context.createGain();        
}

function GotStream(stream) {
   context = new AudioContext();
   nodes = [ new Delay(1,1,1) ]; //Start point of error
   ...
}
```

Obviously its stripped a bit, but that is the exact nesting of functions/variables. I should note I've tried adding `.call(window)`, and `.bind(window)` to the node constructor with no luck

Comment: I know nothing about the Audio API, but shouldn't it be createDelay instead of createDelayNode? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext

Comment: It actually works both ways. But nothing I do is working. I've even tried wrapping it in a method with no luck.

Comment: And are you sure those methods are supposed to be invoked with `new`?

Comment: Yes they are constructors. Which is why I can't attach bind to the end of them. Since then it says `Uncaught TypeError: function bind() { [native code] } is not a constructor `

Comment: Wait, actually removing `new` gets rid of the error. Still nothing happening but no error. This is wierd since all documentaion as well as my own inline testing uses the `new` keyword.

Comment: Try without `new`anyway; I don't see it being used as a constructor at http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/. And it seems createDelayNode is deprecated. The examples I see in the spec use `var something = context.createDelay()`

Comment: Yeah. I'll give that a go. I mean the Web Audio API has only been functional for about a year or less. So rapid changes where warned.

Comment: BINGO THAT FIXED IT. With my new live delay on my webcam microphone my keyboard sounds a lot faster then it is. Any idea why `new` was throwing it off? For the answer that is?

Comment: I guess it wasn't supposed to be used as a constructor. Once you used it as such, you were forcing the wrong `this` value inside the constructor code.

Comment: Well if you wanna write it up I can give you the cred. Otherwise thanks for the solution.